# if table value does not exist echo text?

Tags: php, mysql

Please could someone explain to me how could I adapt my code to make it so that if a record / value doesnt exist in the mysql table it will echo a piece of text? Thank you.

```
<?php

$reviews_set = get_reviews();

 ?>
<h3>Latest Reviews</h3>
<?php
while ($reviews = mysql_fetch_array($reviews_set)) {
 ?>
 <div class="prof-content-box" id="reviews">
 <div class="message_pic">
 <?php echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$reviews['from_user_id']}\"><img width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\"  src=\"{$prof_photo}\"></a>";?>
 <?php echo "<strong>Review from  {$reviews['display_name']}:</strong><br /><br/> {$reviews['content']}     <br />";


  ?>
```

Comment: Check your loop ,make an edit to your question

Comment: As in, you have no records in your database table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php

     $reviews_set = get_reviews();

   ?>
   <h3>Latest Reviews</h3>
   <?php
    if(mysql_num_rows($reviews =  mysql_fetch_array($reviews_set))>=1)
    {
    while ($reviews = mysql_fetch_array($reviews_set)) {
    ?>
    <div class="prof-content-box" id="reviews">
    <div class="message_pic">
    <?php echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$reviews['from_user_id']}\"><img width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\"  src=\"{$prof_photo}\"></a>";?>
    <?php echo "<strong>Review from  {$reviews['display_name']}:</strong><br /><br/>    {$reviews['content']}     <br />";
    }
    } else {
    echo 'No reviews available';
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't close the while before the else. Honestly I usually use foreach rather than while in that case, since you're checking for records before running it foreach is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use the ternary operator '?:'

Sample:

```
$you_var ?: 'you_text_if_not_exists'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your variables like that :

```
<?php (isset($reviews['display_name']) ? $reviews['display_name'] : "entry doesn't exists"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if table has rows, use following:

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($reviews_set);
```

`$num_rows` will contain number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $reviews_set = get_reviews();
    ?>
    <h3>Latest Reviews</h3>
    <?php
    if(mysql_num_rows($reviews_set) > 0) {
        while ($reviews = mysql_fetch_array($reviews_set)) {
            ?>
            <div class="prof-content-box" id="reviews">
             <div class="message_pic">
             <?php echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$reviews['from_user_id']}\"><img width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\"  src=\"{$prof_photo}\"></a>";?>
             <?php echo "<strong>Review from  {$reviews['display_name']}:</strong><br /><br/> {$reviews['content']}     <br />";
        <? 
        }
    }else{
      echo "No Data";
    }

    ?>
```

I hope this helps